# View not MockView for WebView in android studio on developing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, android-source

When I work in android studio and press "Go To > declaration" on WebView class I get class that extends from MockView, is it possible to view real WebView class?
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a5408e6/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java